# Get names of excel worksheets in Elixir / Erlang

Tags: excel, erlang, elixir

There's a very convenient way of reading Excel files in Erlang/Elixir using `ODBC`.

For example:

```
def open(src) do
    conn = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
    DBQ=#{src};"

    {:ok, pid} =
      :odbc.connect(to_charlist(conn),
        timeout: 10000,
        binary_strings: :on,
        tuple_row: :off,
        scrollable_cursors: :off,
        trace_driver: :off,
        extended_errors: :on
      )

    result = :odbc.sql_query(pid, to_charlist("select * from [Sheet1$]"))

    :odbc.disconnect(pid)

   result
end
```

However this requires that we *know the name* of the excel sheets ahead of time.

Is there a way to get the list of **sheet-names** from the Excel file?

what would be the equivalent of `OdbcConnection.GetSchema("Tables")` in Erlang ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at [the source code for the Erlang ODBC server](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/odbc/c_src/odbcserver.c). If I understand correctly, getting a list of tables requires calling the `SQLTables` function in the ODBC library, but there is no such call in the server - so as far as I can tell this is currently not possible.  (A pull request implementing this would probably be welcomed)

Comment: My thoughts exactly. As a matter of fact, I feel Erlang ODBC is in need  of a major update

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/sqltables-excel-driver?view=sql-server-2017